# Modelform not saving data even tho it is being executed

Tags: django, django-forms

The other posts that have this same question didnt actually help me so i decided to ask, problem is a little weird. Bcs the form.save command is being executed, at least i think but when i take a look at my db by the admin page, it doesnt work, and i dont know y, interesting enough the data is displayed in the print and the sucess message is displayed, if any extra information is needed i will gladly give it.

Here it is the base model

```py
class DadoDB(models.Model):
    marca=models.CharField(max_length = 30, default ="ACURA")
    modelo=models.CharField(max_length = 30, default="XWZ")
    ano=models.IntegerField(default= 2021)
    status=models.CharField(max_length= 10,default= "BOM")
    cor=models.CharField(max_length= 10, default= "VERMELHO")
    combustivel=models.CharField(max_length= 10,default= "FLEX")
    quilometragem=models.DecimalField(max_digits= 10,decimal_places=2,max_length= 12,default=100)
    lucro=models.DecimalField(max_digits= 10,decimal_places=2,max_length= 12,default=100)
    preco=models.DecimalField(max_digits= 10,decimal_places=2,max_length= 12,default=100)
    margem_de_lucro=models.DecimalField(max_digits= 10,decimal_places=2,max_length= 12,default=100)
    data_postada = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    autor= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Empresa'
```

Here it is the base form

```
from django import forms
from .models import DadoDB

class InsiraDadosForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
      model = DadoDB
      ['marca','modelo','ano','status','cor','combustivel'....
```

Here is the view

```
@login_required
def InserirDado(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = InsiraDadosForm(request.POST,instance= request.user)
       if form.is_valid():
             form.save()
             print(request.POST)
             messages.success(request, f'Seus dados foram inseridos com sucesso!')
             return redirect('dado-InserirDado')
    else:
       form = InsiraDadosForm()
    return render(request, 'dado/inserirdado.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: `instance=request.user`?

Comment: You aim to save the data to the logged in user, but this user model has no `marca`, `modelo`, `ano`, etc. field. So you add extra attributes to the model object and then when saving that object, that of course does not work.

Comment: i see just out of curiosity, why does the action form.save() still executes even tho i am adding infos to nothing?

Comment: @NGl0R1AM0R1: because if you do not specify an instance Django will construct a *new* instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `instance=request.user` makes no sense. This means you are going to *edit* the logged in user record. But that is not a `DadoDB` object, so you will set attributes on the logged in user, and when saving the user, there will be no changes, not even to that suer object, since the user has no fields like `cor`, `ano`, etc.

```
@login_required
def InserirDado(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # no instance=request.user ↓
        form = InsiraDadosForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.autor = request.user
            form.save()
            print(request.POST)
            messages.success(request, f'Seus dados foram inseridos com sucesso!')
            return redirect('dado-InserirDado')
    else:
       form = InsiraDadosForm()
    return render(request, 'dado/inserirdado.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help really appreciate it, i am guessing the templater error  i am receiveing, when trying to display the data on admin is it bcs of those misplaced instances right?

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1: exactly *what* template error?

Comment: 'DadoDB' object has no attribute 'user',

Comment: For some weird reason it displays this line,   as the causer                                                               <a href="{% url 'admin:password_change' %}">{% translate 'Change password' %}</a> /

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1: that has nothing to do with the view, likely this is because you specified authentication urls, without the `admin` namespace.

Comment: I did specify two auth_views, here is one.  path('Login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='usuarios/login.html'), name= 'Login'), what do i need to do fix it? i never heard of this admin namespace requirement

Comment: It's not about a login, it's about a `PasswordChangeView`. Please ask a *new* question, and share the urls you have changed.

Comment: Okay i shall, i think it is conflicting with the password reset mail urls. Nonetheless thank u for the help.